How to prevent query strings from being attached to the URL when blocking navigation?
I created this hook to stop warn the user that they have unsaved form changes (React Hook Form). This also works when the user is, say, switching tabs: the code checks for query strings like these: ?tab=vcard. Everything works well...except ?tab=vcard is attached to the URL, so you will see the, say, other tab briefly.
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { useRouter, usePathname, useSearchParams } from 'next/navigation';

export const useUnsaved = (isDirty: boolean) => {
  const router = useRouter();
  const pathname = usePathname();
  const searchParams = useSearchParams();

  const [prevQueryString, setPrevQueryString] = useState(() =>
    searchParams.toString(),
  );

  useEffect(() => {
    const handleBeforeUnload = (event: BeforeUnloadEvent) => {
      if (isDirty) {
        event.preventDefault();
      }
    };

    window.addEventListener('beforeunload', handleBeforeUnload);
    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener('beforeunload', handleBeforeUnload);
    };
  }, [isDirty]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const currentQueryString = searchParams.toString();
    if (isDirty && currentQueryString !== prevQueryString) {
      const confirmLeave = window.confirm(
        'You have unsaved changes. Are you sure you want to leave this page?',
      );
      if (!confirmLeave) {
        // Prevent navigation by restoring the previous state
        router.push(`${pathname}?${prevQueryString}`);
        return; // Stop execution without throwing an error
      } else {
        setPrevQueryString(currentQueryString); // Update to the new query string
      }
    }
  }, [isDirty, pathname, searchParams, prevQueryString, router]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const originalPush = router.push;
    router.push = async (url: string, ...args: any[]) => {
      const currentQueryString = searchParams.toString();
      const fullCurrentPath = `${pathname}?${currentQueryString}`;
      if (isDirty && url !== fullCurrentPath) {
        const confirmLeave = window.confirm(
          'You have unsaved changes. Are you sure you want to leave this page?',
        );
        if (!confirmLeave) {
          // Prevent navigation by staying on the current path
          router.push(fullCurrentPath);
          return; // Just return here, no error thrown
        }
      }
      return originalPush(url, ...args);
    };

    return () => {
      router.push = originalPush;
    };
  }, [isDirty, pathname, searchParams, router]);
};

So I think I need to stop Next.js from attaching the query string to the URL, and only proceed if the user clicks "Ok." How can I accomplish this?

Can you clarify your question? If I understand it correctly, you are using query params to check if the user is changing tabs and using these hook to warn them, but instead you want the user to be warned without them seeing which tabs they're on, basically you wanted to warned them without relying on query params?
